# Why does Damon kill these characters in the movie The Signal?

Tags: the-signal

I recently watched the movie *[The Signal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Signal_(2014_film))*, and was not able to understand the reason or motive behind Damon killing a couple of people.

Firstly, Mirabelle, the old lady who says, “They are watching us” and starts repeating some phrase; and secondly, the gas station clerk who is in a house and says that this is “is house”.

Why does Damon kill these two people?

Comment: Hello kartik. I have edited your title to remove spoilers from it (and make it a bit shorter), incorporating the removed bits into the body of the question instead. If I've misunderstood something (I haven't seen the movie), please feel free to edit again and fix it.

Answer (score 1):

The impression I got was that those two subjects were starting to break down and therefore he killed them as a mercy-killing. It's ambiguous as to whether they'd been experimented on, or if they'd simply cracked psychologically, but both of them had started ranting with Mirabelle repeating the same phrases and sounds over and over again.